# How to move contents of folder to the parent folder in GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

The title kinda says it all. Here is my situation. I was moving files around in my bucket but for some reason it got interrupted. I tried resuming, but wound up having a weird filing system. Now what I have is that most of my files are in

`my_bucket/info/downloaded`

but some (those I tried moving after the interruption) wound up in

`my_bucket/info/downloaded/downloaded`.

I want to move all the contents of the latter into the former, so essentially I want to move all files in a folder into the parent in my GCS bucket.

I've tried using the command

`gcloud storage mv my_bucket/info/downloaded/downloaded my_bucket/info/downloaded`

but that doesn't work, it just copies the files to the same place. I then tried to move what I wanted to move into a third folder as follows

`gcloud storage mv my_bucket/info/downloaded/downloaded my_bucket/extra`

and then after that used

`gcloud storage mv my_bucket/extra my_bucket/info/downloaded`

but this just ended up moving everything into a folder `my_bucket/info/downloaded/extra`. Is there a command I can run to get the structure I want?

Comment: I would try: `gcloud storage mv my_bucket/extra/* my_bucket/info/downloaded`  (But I have never done anything using gcloud...)   The idea is that you move the files in the directory extra (by specifying `/*`, and not the directory `extra`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can use wildcards with `gcloud storage mv`, as Luuk in the comments suggests, however when doing so one must use single quotes to prevent the shell from trying to expand. So the kind of command you would run is

`gcloud storage mv 'gs://my_bucket/extra/*' gs://my_bucket/info/downloaded`.